# How to fix foreign key error when running migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-6, laravel-migrations

I don't know why it's still don't work and show this:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `db_rocnikovka`.`books` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `books` add constraint `books_doba_foreign` foreign key (`doba`)
>   references `druh_knihies` (`id_druhu`))
>
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\Rocnikovka\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:665
>
> Exception trace:
>    1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create > table `db_rocnikovka`.`books` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\Rocnikovka\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

2   PDOStatement::execute()

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\Rocnikovka\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459
```

```
 catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new QueryException(
       $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    );
 }
```

**First table**

```php
class CreateDruhKnihiesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('druh_knihies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_druhu');
            $table->string('nazev');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('druh_knihies');
    }
}
```

**Second table**

```php
class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_book');
            $table->string('nazev');
            $table->string('autor');
            $table->string('druh');
            $table->unsignedInteger('doba');
            $table->foreign('doba')->references('id_druhu')->on('druh_knihies');
            $table->integer('pocet_stranek');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `druh_knihies` table exists when you are creating `books` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You foreign key needs to have the same type as the key it references. Therefor the second table foreign key `doba` needs to be change to this, becuase you use `BigIncrements()` in the first table primary key.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('doba');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `id_druhu` in `druh_knihies` is defined as `bigIncrements` and you create `doba` as `unsignedInteger` and when using foreign key type should be exactly same. So in this case instead of

```
$table->unsignedInteger('doba');
```

you should use

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('doba');
```